# How do I play a crossed note before a hammer-on?

Tags: guitar, acoustic-guitar, fingerstyle-guitar, ornaments

The tab below is from **Stop this Train - John Mayer**

How am I suppose to play the part circled in red?

Also what is the correct name for this notation?

[image: Stop This Train - John Mayer]

Comment: The redirection of your question explains that these notes are grace notes that have no rhythmic value (because of the slashes they have). However part of your question is not answered by the answers of the other question, which is how to play them. In both cases you want to strike the open E string then immediately hammer the 2nd fret. The first one is as part of a D chord and the second is hammering the note on the high E string while playing the low E 2nd fret at the same time.

Comment: @JohnBelzaguy - good point. The 'dupe' asks **what** the signs mean, with nothing in the answers explaining how to execute on guitar. Vote to re-open? Then your comment could be an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is *accacciatura*, see:

- [Difference between appoggiatura, acciaccatura and grace note](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/91410/difference-between-appoggiatura-acciaccatura-and-grace-note?rq=1)
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ornament_(music)#Acciaccatura

The way to perform it is basically explained in the tabulature. You play the crossed note together with the other notes of the chord, and then, rather quickly, hammer on the following, not crossed note.